# How to get the correct DateTime in a REACT's form field?

Tags: java, reactjs

I'm creating a CRUD app using Spring Boot and React.
The app is able to get all data with correct DateTime from BE.

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

The problem is when I want to update a row.
When I click on "update" the form autocompile with all data except the date.

```
<Col className="px-1" md="3">
    <FormGroup>
        <label>Data di Inizio</label>
        <Input type="datetime-local" step="1" name="startDate" id="startDate"
               onChange={this.onChange}
               value={this.state.startDate === null ? '' : this.state.startDate}/>
    </FormGroup>
</Col>
```

If I check in console the value is corrected "01-09-2019 12:00:00" but in the form I've got "dd/mm/yyyy --:--:--" with the option to chose a date from the calendar.

How can I get the correct DateTime selected inside the field?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the format from BE in:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  Try:
     <input type="datetime-local"
     value={this.state.datatime}
     onChange={e => tho=is.handleChange('datetime', e)}
     />

      and handleChange is reusable for other inputs like so:
       handleChange = (field,e) => {
       this.setState({ [field]: e.target.value});
       };
```